# How can i set a background image to a image which in being generated dynamically

Tags: c#, gdi

I am creating some dynamic image using the following code

```
System.Drawing.Image img = new Bitmap(300, 600);

Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);

//paint the background
drawing.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);

//create a brush for the text
Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(textColor);

drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, 0, 0);

drawing.Save();

textBrush.Dispose();
drawing.Dispose();
```

Instead of white backgroung i want to use an image (company logo) so that it act like a water mark. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Change your textBrush definition to look ike this:

```
int alpha = 128; // range from 0 (transparent) to 255 (opaque)
Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha, textColor);
```